# How to document control flow of a website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I've built a fairly complex web app (html, javascript, jQuery, php, mySQL) and use several mechanisms for navigating through the site (e.g. anchor/links, submit buttons, window.location, window.open).  I'm looking for two things:

1. What are all the mechanisms possible for moving around a site or a source that will allow me to find such a list
2. What, if any, documentation standards are there for documenting such actions; something like the flow charts used to document procedural code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "what are all the possible mechanisms for moving around"? Like clicking links and editing the address bar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure either by what you mean in "thing 1".  The best tool to map all the paths is the [UML Sequence Diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm).

Comment: by source I mean a book or a website article that focuses particularly on the various ways of getting data from / to the server (e.g. window.location,  submit button click, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Services such as Omniture and Google Analytics let you visualize such paths of user navigation. You could explore that option. Basically they work by tracking a page's URL and its referrer URL (accessible via `document.referrer`) and then making the connection.

Comment: Will they let me know / see the mechanism (window.location, submit button click, ...) that altered the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comment on dj_segfault properly, I'm not even sure you understand the concept of server/client interaction.

I don't think there is an answer to this because the technology is changing all the time and it is different depending on what devices you are using.

You only have to look at Node.js (if you understand the technology) to see that the lines between server and client can be blurred, and that it's just not a simple answer.

The bottom line is in fact there are no navigation "things" unless you program them, and how you program them is your choice depending on requirement.

For example a vanilla link

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Can either be static HTML content or echo'ed from a php script which was used to select the data from a database to get the URL and print it. But it doesn't have to be either of these.

If you wanted to navigate to google you could use a button with an onClick javascript or an event listener with data collected by AJAX. It could be derived from other content values on-the-fly or be a string. I could probably imagine 20 different possibilities but that doesn't make them all suitable for the application.

Just keep incrementally improving your project, use this forum to answer specific questions and you'll learn a lot. I did.

Comment: T9b, thanks for the response.  In the example you give, I view the mechanism to be only a “link,” whether placed in the html page source as a sting of characters or generated by PHP, it’s the same thing.  
The suggestion of the UML Sequence Diagram has the best potential for use but it, in and of itself, doesn’t regulate the documentation of the “mechanism.”  Maybe I’m looking for something that doesn’t exist, or I’m asking the question in the wrong way; I was hoping there was some common, industry standard for doing this that I had not stumbled across yet.  Thanks again for the thoughts.